# How to write a sequence

Tags: r

I want to write this sequence in R, 
1, 1/3, 1/5,1/7,...,1/21
I have:

```
x <- seq(1,21,by=2)  
y<- 1/x
print(y)
```

I got:

```
1.00000000 0.33333333 0.20000000 0.14285714 0.11111111 0.09090909 0.07692308 0.06666667 0.05882353 0.05263158 0.04761905
```

which is the same as the sequence,

Now is there another way to get the numbers as fraction without using the fraction package?

Comment: `paste0("1/",seq(1, 21, 2))`

Answer (score 5):

Try using the `as.fractions` in the MASS package

```
 x <- seq(1,21,by=2)
  y<- 1/x
  MASS::as.fractions(y)
  [1]    1  1/3  1/5  1/7  1/9 1/11 1/13 1/15 1/17 1/19 1/21
```

Comment: Didnt know this function - quite kool : `MASS::as.fractions(y) + sqrt(2)` even works

Comment: That only does approximations.. Maybe if there is a surd fuction I do not know about that yet

Comment: ive not properly looked, but probably the print  (and fractions) method  - the fractions that we see - are approx. But the underlying numeric, *I think* will be the same (`all.equal(MASS::as.fractions(y)  + sqrt(2), y + sqrt(2), check.attributes=FALSE)`) (could wrap fractions in as.numeric to remove message)